# sort filenames by the numbers after the last occurence of a character

Tags: bash, shell

I want to sort the filenames by the numbers after the last occurence of `s`, How to do it?

For example:

```
01002M00T1relaxouspios1001a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxos301a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxos201a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxouspios901a001.nii
```

The sorted filenames should be:

```
01002M00T1relaxos201a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxos301a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxouspios901a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxouspios1001a001.nii
```

I tried to use

```
$sort -ts -nk2,4
```

But it only works for the first 2 filenames.

Example 2:

```
01002M00T1relaxos201a001.nii 
01002M00T1relaxouspios1001a001.nii 
01002M00T130relaxos301a001.nii 
01002M00T130relaxouspios901a001.ni
```

Expected Output:

```
01002M00T1relaxos201a001.nii 
01002M00T130relaxos301a001.nii 
01002M00T130relaxouspios901a001.ni
01002M00T1relaxouspios1001a001.nii
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, do a version sort using the `-V` option:

```
$ sort -V file

01002M00T1relaxos201a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxos301a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxouspios901a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxouspios1001a001.nii
```

*Edit after 2nd example posted.*

**General Case:**

```
$ ls | awk -Fs '{print $NF, $0}' | sort -n | awk '{print $2}'

01002M00T1relaxos201a001.nii
01002M00T130relaxos301a001.nii
01002M00T130relaxouspios901a001.ni
01002M00T1relaxouspios1001a001.nii
```

Comment: No. This does not work, for example:   `01002M00T1relaxos201a001.nii  `
`01002M00T1relaxouspios1001a001.nii`
`01002M00T130relaxos301a001.nii`
`01002M00T130relaxouspios901a001.nii`

Comment: This  work for the example you **gave** and btw you're welcome.

Comment: Interesting solution with Awk. Using the `$NF` and separating the fields on the `s` is very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a programming language like Perl or Python that give you a bit more of an ability to specify what you want to sort, but if you insist on BASH, you'll have to employ a little trick:

You can create a sort key using `sed`, sort based upon that sort key you created, and then remove that key by using `sed:

```
ls | sed 's/\(.*s\)\(.*\)/\1\2 ^ \2)
```

The above uses the greedy powers of regular expressions to get what you want. The `\(.*s\)` will match everything to the final lowercase `s`. The `\(.*\)` will match everything that `s`. The `\1` and `\2` match the various sections captured in the `\(...\)` groups. Thus, I have two strings; The first is the name of the file, the second is the sorting string. The output will look like this:

```
$ ls | sed 's/\(.*s\)\(.*\)/\1\2 ^ \2/'
01002M00T1relaxouspios1001a001.nii ^ 1001a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxos301a001.nii ^ 301a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxos201a001.nii ^ 201a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxouspios901a001.nii ^ 901a001.nii
```

Now, I can sort on the part after the `^`:

```
$ ls | sed 's/\(.*s\)\(.*\)/\1\2 ^ \2/' | sort -t^ -k2.2
01002M00T1relaxouspios1001a001.nii ^ 1001a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxos201a001.nii ^ 201a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxos301a001.nii ^ 301a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxouspios901a001.nii ^ 901a001.nii
```

Now, all I have to do is remove that sort key:

```
$ ls | sed 's/\(.*s\)\(.*\)/\1\2 ^ \2/' | sort -t^ -k2.2| sed 's/ ^ .*//'
01002M00T1relaxouspios1001a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxos201a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxos301a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxouspios901a001.nii
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. It works, except with this small correction: use -nk2.2 instead of -k2.2.

Comment: Simpler to put the key at the front and *cleaner* with `awk`, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is an elegant **bash only** solution if the number **is uniq** and sufficient to be an index.
The idea is to use `bash array` but not `associative`:

```
unset sortedlist
declare -a sortedlist
while read filename;do
    [[ $filename =~ s([0-9]+)[a-rt-z][^s]*$ ]] &&
       sortedlist[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=$filename
  done < <(ls)
printf "%s\n" "${sortedlist[@]}"
01002M00T1relaxos201a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxos301a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxouspios901a001.nii
01002M00T1relaxouspios1001a001.nii
```

Nota: in an *array*, fields are sorted in numerical order, so `1001` is greater than `901`.

Nota2: as `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` is a condition, filenames not matching the *regular expression* would simply by ignored.

Comment: I guess we define *elegant* very differently.

Comment: Yes, it is! In that, there is no fork to `sed` nor to `sort`. At all, everything's relative!